# Ansible Registers - Dynamic naming

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use a register in Ansible playbook to store my output. Below is the code which i am using.

I have tried below code

```
- name: Check if Service Exists
  stat: path=/etc/init.d/{{ item }}
  register: {{ item }}_service_status
  with_items:
     - XXX
     - YYY
     - ZZZ
```

I need different outputs to be stored in different register variables based on the items as mentioned in the code. It is failing and not able to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What part is failing? Can you post the error message?

Comment: Also, can you show how you will use the dynamic variables elsewhere in the code based on their names?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer**

I think you need to put quotes around it:

```
register: "{{ item }}_service_status"
```

Or you can use `set_fact` ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44073969/4057186), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208860/255869), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29817564/4057186), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43633611/4057186))

- register all the output to a single static variable `output` and then use a loop to iteratively build a new variable `service_status` (a [list](https://everythingshouldbevirtual.com/automation/ansible-defining-variables-as-dictionaries/)) by looping over each item in the static variable `output`

```
- name: Check if Service Exists
  stat: path=/etc/init.d/{{ item }}
  register: output
  with_items:
     - XXX
     - YYY
     - ZZZ

- name: Setting fact using output of loop
  set_fact:
    service_status:
      - rc: "{{ item.rc }}"
        stdout: "{{ item.stdout }}"
        id: "{{ item.id }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ output }}"

- debug:
    msg: "ID and stdout: {{ item.id }} - {{ item.stdout }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ service_status }}"
```

---

**Initial Answer**

IIUC, [this link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop) from the Ansible docs shows how to use `register` inside a loop (see another example in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29636407/4057186)).

A couple of points

- it may be more convenient to assign the list (`XXX, YYY, ZZZ`) to a separate variable (eg. [1](http://www.mydailytutorials.com/the-basics-of-ansible-variables/), [2](http://www.oznetnerd.com/ansible-vars-lists/))
- I don't know if this is part of the problem, but `with_items` [is no longer the recommended approach](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop) to loop over a variable: instead use `loop` - see [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items) for an example

```
vars:
  items:
    - XXX
    - YYY
    - ZZZ

- name: Check if Service Exists
  stat: path=/etc/init.d/{{ item }}
  register: service_status
  loop: "{{ items|flatten(levels=1) }}"

- name: Show the return code and stdout
  debug:
    msg: "Cmd {{ item.cmd }}, return code {{ item.rc }}, stdout {{ item.stdout }}"
  when: item.rc != 0
  with_items: "{{ service_status.results }}"
```

Comment: I am here looking for the name of the register to be dynamic. Is it not possible? Because I am planning to use that register else where in the code based on the name.

Comment: @SridharAdurthi, thank you for the response. Please see my updated answer.